# Incorrect output from awk function

Tags: awk

I'm a bit new to coding, but I'm using someone's code to process some sequencing data and am encountering an issue with the awk function not generating the output in the appropriate fasta file format.

Here is the first few lines of the input fastq file:

```
@M02357:681:000000000-JDYM7:1:1101:14147:1972 1:N:0:TCCGGAGA+TATAGCCTCTTCTGGGTATT
TTATCCTTACTCTAAAATCGGCTAGCTGGTACGTAGCTCGAGAGGGTCTC
+
@B8AACFE9@CEF,,,,CE,;CF,;CF,,C,C,C<,CFE@+6,+,,8C@@
@M02357:681:000000000-JDYM7:1:1101:11004:1972 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+TATAGCCTAATTTGATTGTC
GCAACCTTGCTATGAGTCGGGCTAGCCTCACCCTACCTACCCCAGCTACT
+
-8,<AEFF9EEAD<<,EEC77@F8@CFEF8EEFE<CEFACC@C@,CFAE,
@M02357:681:000000000-JDYM7:1:1101:14684:1973 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+TATAGCCTTGACTAAGACAA
TTATCCTTCGAGACGGGACGGCTAGCATCACAGGTCCTCGAGTTTAAAGC
+
BC@C@EFFF88,,@,,+,@++@F,6C,CE,C,,,;CEFF7,,CF,,,,,C
@M02357:681:000000000-JDYM7:1:1101:14784:1974 1:N:0:TCCGGAGA+TATAGCCTCTTCGCAAATTT
AACGGAGTTATTCCTATGACGCTAGCAGCGGGCACCCTCGAGCTTCCACC
+
--A8-,+8C,EFEEE,E,,;6BF,6C,,;+++8+BCFDF+,6@CEEF,CC
```

Here is the code I am using to generate a fasta file from the fastq file:

```
awk -F "1:N:0:" 'BEGIN{FS="1:N:0:"; RS="M0"; OFS=""} {print ">", $1, "¥n", substr($2, 1,8),substr($2, 10, 20),substr($2, 31, 30)}' Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq > i7_i5_UMI_read.fa
```

Here is the output fasta file, which for some reason is in this weird format:

```
>@¥n
>02357:681:000000000-JDY¥n
>7:1:1101:14147:1972 ¥nTCCGGAGATATAGCCTCTTCTGGGTATTTTATCCTTACTCTAAAATCGGCTAGCTGGT
>02357:681:000000000-JDY¥n
>7:1:1101:11004:1972 ¥nATTACTCGTATAGCCTAATTTGATTGTCGCAACCTTGCTATGAGTCGGGCTAGCCTCA
>02357:681:000000000-JDY¥n
>7:1:1101:14684:1973 ¥nATTACTCGTATAGCCTTGACTAAGACAATTATCCTTCGAGACGGGACGGCTAGCATCA
>02357:681:000000000-JDY¥n
>7:1:1101:14784:1974 ¥nTCCGGAGATATAGCCTCTTCGCAAATTTAACGGAGTTATTCCTATGACGCTAGCAGCG
```

I am not very familiar with the awk function so I am very confused on what is going on and why it is not generating a fasta file in the appropriate format. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Here's some additional information based on comment questions. When I run `awk --version`, it says `awk version 20070501`. I am not running `GNU awk`, how do I install that tool to be able to use it? Also, when I run `cat -v file`, it says `No such file or directory`. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You're using a multi-char RS (`RS="M0"`) which only GNU awk supports. Are you using GNU awk? What's the output of `awk --version`? Tell us what you think is weird about your output and show us your expected output. [edit] your question to provide all info, don't add it in comments. Oh, and also tell us if your lines end in `LF` or `CRLF` or something else - do `cat -v file` to see what's there if you don't know.

Comment: awk isn't a function by the way, it's a tool. The awk language has functions.

Comment: Hi, I updated the original post to answer your questions, thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @tnf, I believe https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ is a more appropriate home for this type of question, as the users there have the domain-specific expertise to advise you if this tool/approach is a good choice for your task.

Comment: @tnf you still didn't add the output you expect or tell us in what way you consider the output you get to be "weird". You did show us that the awk you're running is not GNU awk though so you can't use an RS values that's more than 2 chars. Get GNU awk then try again. How to get GNU awk depends on the platfrom you're running on - google that. As for `cat -v file` producing "No such file or directory" - replace `file` with the actual name of your input file.